# How to use correct Android theme when using programmatic components?

Tags: android, api, themes

I'm using the default basic app created in Android Studio "New Project". The app is using the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme, and this works fine as it is. I then changed the main activity onCreate() method to use programmatic components only (I have my reasons!), eg:

```
// setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); Removed!

// Added this:
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button.setText("Test");
setContentView(button, lParams);
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

However, now the button appears in the wrong theme. It looks like Holo Dark or something, but the colour is definitely wrong. Also, other components such as EditText also have the wrong theme. The action bar and main background theme appear to be correct.

Is there something else that should be done in order to set the correct theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use multiple themes:

**values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="search_icon">@drawable/ic_action_search_light</item>
    <item name="loading_panel_indicator">@style/LoadingPanelIndicator_Light</item>
    <item name="exp_group_selector">@drawable/exp_group_selection_light</item>
    <item name="list_selector">@drawable/list_selection_light</item>
    <item name="spinner_background">@drawable/spinner_bg_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppDarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="search_icon">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
    <item name="loading_panel_indicator">@style/LoadingPanelIndicator</item>
    <item name="exp_group_selector">@drawable/exp_group_selection</item>
    <item name="list_selector">@drawable/list_selection</item>
    <item name="spinner_background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
</style>
```

and in your activity's onCreate:

```
    isThemeLight = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_LIGHT_THEME, true);
    if (!isThemeLight)
        setTheme(R.style.AppDarkTheme);
```

And have your default theme always set in the manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

Once you change the theme, the activity must be re-created. Here's a piece of code to be used after you change the theme (e.g. @ onRestart() but it depends on when you are changing it):

```
boolean isLight = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_LIGHT_THEME, true);
// If theme changed re-create the activity
if (isThemeLight != isLight) {
    // Call the recreate in the UI thread
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recreate();
        }
    }, 1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I have done (please see edited post above with included xml files). Yet still the theme does not work if I use programmatic components but does work if I use the layout file instead.

Comment: @chris I left the most important part out. See the updated answer.

Comment: This still doesn't work actually. Technically I'm not changing the theme, I'm still using the default "AppTheme" as set in the manifest. I tried it anyway though and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: It appears as though the inflation version of setContentView() is doing something that the non-inflation version is not doing??

Comment: @chris have you tried setting another theme in your manifest? If the button is still with a different style then the problem lies within your xml or the style itself, not the way you are changing it.

Comment: @chris also I hope you used the default layout when trying my suggestions (`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`).